# Dragon Player Characters

Tags: game-recommendation

Are there any good rpgs where the player characters are dragons?

I am familiar with the old D&D supplement "Council of Wyrms", but that was just screwing with some basic D&D stats and trying to wedge in dragon characters.  (The setting was reasonably good though.)

Are there any built from the ground up on this theme?

Comment: There's some coverage of this material here. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6027/what-are-some-resources-or-tips-on-dragons-as-pcs

Comment: As this is a [tag:system-recommendation] question, please adhere to both the [FAQ] and the rules for subjective questions as outlined in [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and on [our Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/1071/760).  In particular, all responses should be based on actual experience and contain references and examples whenever possible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [Fireborn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireborn) RPG, released in 2004, features player characters who are dragons, shapeshifted to hide among humans in the modern day. Key to gameplay are "flashback" sequences, reflecting the great age and historical impact of dragonkind — it's a little like Highlander that way.

Comment: Thank you this looks great.  Picked up all 3 books from DriveThroughRPG (as pdf) for $15.  My daughter is so excited.

Comment: One of the coolest combat systems I've ever seen too. Great recommendation.

Comment: I came here to give this answer. Even though I ended up selling all my books, it was absolutely an interesting game. One note - Stay **far away** from the pregenerated adventure. It pretty much drove my players crazy with inconsistencies and almost ruined the whole game for us.

Comment: Had to dig after leaving the wiki, but that system can be found [here](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=236&esem=2). +1 good find

Answer (score 4):

Castle Falkenstein includes Dragons as a primary character race. They are vital to the setting as presented, but vary considerably from the stereotypical dragon in body form...

CF's dragons are intelligent, magic using pterosaurs... Pterodraconis sapiens. Aside from this, they hold to the standard conventions: magic using, shape-shifting, flying and fire-breathing.

Comment: I had forgotten about CF's dragons!

Answer (score 2):

And no one answered, "Monsters, Monsters", the spin-off a tunnells and trolls?
Not enough Old School Love.
http://www.trollandtoad.com/p303719.html

Comment: Dragons are SO overpowered in it... It's available on DriveThruRPG.com, too. US$6 last I checked. However, it's actually a T&T rework, not designed from the ground up.

Answer (score 2):

[On the Ecology of the Mud Dragon](http://swingpad.com/dustyboots/wordpress/?p=296) actually requires you to be a dragon! Oh, well, it's a devoluted, nowadays dragon that lives in junkyards and steals candies to babies but hey, I think this game fully addresses your question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Palladium Fantasy RPG](https://palladium-store.com/1001/category/Palladium-Fantasy-RPG.html), and by extension Rifts, allow player characters such as dragons with no conversion or alterations necessary.

A necessary supplement for such an endeavour using the 2nd Edition of the rules includes the [Dragons and Gods](https://palladium-store.com/1001/product/451-Dragons-and-Gods.html) book, which has a section dealing with playing dragons specifically. The book has notes on culture, maturation, drives, a deeper look into their natural abilities, experience charts, and all the species in one volume.

The [first edition](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product_info.php?products_id=60661) of the rules can be found as a pdf download from DrivethruRPG. If opting to use this edition of the rules, dragons can be found in the core book, with full stat and ability ranges for generation, but less overall social/cultural information, making the Dragons and Gods book fairly useful for both approaches.

Comment: The first released Palladium game has no dragons at all, being *Mechanoids: The Journey*, and is the same game engine. Your answer is akin to suggesting GURPS or Hero... a generic engine that just happens to include Dragons as characters in a later edition.

Answer (score 1):

[Fantasy Craft](http://www.crafty-games.com/node/348) is a toolkit system. The core rulebook includes a Drake character species, which is pretty close to being a dragon. The species includes fire breathing and claws, but not opposable thumbs or the ability to fit through a door designed for humans. It could form the base of such a campaign.