# Modern occult game focused around dragon characters

Tags: product-identification, dragons, modern

What is the game with the modern occult setting, where the players can play dragons?

It is mostly played in England, and the characters can remember their dragon's life.

Comment: You'll need to give far more information than that. Are you asking about a game you've played, but don't know the name of? Or are you looking for a system that does this?

Comment: @waxeagle It appears that it was, indeed, enough! It's funny to see how some stuff may be seen vague to us but clear to others.

Answer (score 7):

[Fireborn](http://www.fantasyflightgames.com/edge_minisite_sec.asp?eidm=236&esem=1) by Fantasy Flight Games.

Answer (score 4):

That one's [Fireborn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fireborn). We've [discussed it a little](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/8863/dragon-player-characters/8867#8867) here.